# Unity: trigger collision not registering

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a Kart racing game in unity and have created a map, car and finish-line
The collisions between the car and the map works but the finish-line has been set to trigger so that the car can go through/over it, this is not working.

## The car

[image]

## The collision script (in the cars code)

[image]

## The finish line

[image]

Thanks in advance as I am confused and lost as to why this is not functioning

I have tried setting the collision event as a non triggered (to confirm the code runs) and this works
and have tried with the commented line onTriggerEnter2D() to find that this does not work

Comment: Can you check if the Car and Finish Line object are on same layer?

Comment: They are both in the default layer and have a z position of 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the others already said I think OnTriggerEnter would be the way to go.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnTriggerEnter2D.html
Looking at the example from unity I see a difference in the parameters.
You did
`OnTriggerEnter2D(Collision2D col)`
while the example does `OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)`.

Maybe changing Collision to Collider already solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    //code
}
```

use this instead of OnCollisionEnter.

OnCollisionEnter - collision with objects that are not trigger.

OnTriggerEnter - collision with triggers.

And i suggest instead of getting from `gameObject.Tag == "FinishLine"` use : `gameObject.CompareTag("FinishLine")`.

Comment: As you can see from the commented out line I have attempted the onTriggerEnter2D and had no success

Answer (score 0):

You should use `OnTriggerEnter` to track triggers collisions.

Docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html

Comment: you should be able to see that in the commented out code i used OnTriggerEnter2D() but that failed, I assume that I should use the 2d variant due to everything in the project being 2d

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a kinematic rigidbody to your finish line object. And enable kinematic-dynamic collisions in "Project Settings > Physics > Contacts Pair Mode" to "Enable All Contacts". I hope it helps.

Comment: Did you try it yourself ? It's better to a have strong conviction that a solution will effectively solve the problem before posting.

Comment: yes i tried it myself